# Incorporating python/web2py app into wordpress site

Tags: python, wordpress, web2py

I have been asked to implement a type of logging system into an existing website. The site was not developed by me, it is a small company owned by a friend and I am doing it as a favour for no charge. It was made in Wordpress and is hosted on his own server.

I have no significant PHP experience but I have created a pretty decent web app using Python/web2py and ideally would like to use this again.

Would this be possible to build it into the existing site or would it be a better idea to build a standalone app and host it on the same server? I have no real experience at this level so sorry if this is a stupid question

Comment: Its not advisable to go around messing with wordpress' internal framework if that is not what you are looking for. If you just want to access data, connect straight to the wordpress database for logging information

Comment: @cggaurav There isn't even an existing DB yet. It's just a HTML site really providing information about the company. The development company wanted a lot of money to implement the logging system so I offered my (limited) services instead. Basically, I'm better off just linking to the web2py app instead?

Comment: The statements that "it was made in WordPress" and "there isn't an existing DB" are not compatible, as are "it was made in WordPress" and "its just an HTML site". WordPress would not work without a database. Can you clear up what you are talking about?

Comment: @s_ha_dum sorry there may be an existing database but its not populated so. I haven't seen the code and I've never worked with Wordpress so forgive me if I'm way off the mark

Comment: WordPress is a PHP/MySQL application. It must have a database and a populated one to work. If there is a working WordPress install, there is a database and there is stuff in it. Not knowing what your Python app does it is hard to say answer your primary question, but most likely it will need to run side-by-side with WordPress.

Comment: @s_ha_dum thats probably the best course of action and is certainly the way I'm leaning. I just thought someone may have done it before so was worth asking. Thanks for the input